# Error con SQLite en una segunda tabla

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite

Buenas, mi error radica en que mi app al desarrollarse con una sola tabla esta funciona a la perfeccion pero al intentar adicionar una segunda, al momento de usarla esta se cierra...

**SQLite** (clase donde tengo la creacion de mi base de datos...)

```
package company.viral.organizadorjec.ActivitysPrincipales;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by erny on 27/10/2016.
 */

public class SQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //constructor.......
    public SQLite(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }



    //aqui se crea la tabla...
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table usuarios (id_usuario integer primary key autoincrement,usuario text, clave text)");

        db.execSQL("create table profesores (id_profesor integer primary key autoincrement,nombreprofesor text, comentarioprofesor text)");





        db.execSQL("insert into usuarios values('0','admin','admin')");
        db.execSQL("insert into profesores values('0','alfonso','pirata')");


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("create table usuarios (id_usuario integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "usuario text, clave text)");

        db.execSQL("create table profesores (id_profesor integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "nombreprofesor text, comentarioprofesor text)");


        db.execSQL("insert into usuarios values('0','admin','admin')");
        db.execSQL("insert into profesores values('0','alfonso','autobus')");



    }
}
```

**Main Activity** (clase que usa mi primera tabla para el acceso al sistema-el cual es un `Navigation Drawer`)

```
package company.viral.organizadorjec.ActivitysPrincipales;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import company.viral.organizadorjec.R;

//aqui empieza...
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //creamos variables EditText para capturar los datos
    private EditText aetid,aetpass;
    private Cursor fila;


    //en este metodo SIEMPRE se dibuja la app correspondiente
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //antes de dibujar definimos las variables y a quienes pertecen en el layout

        aetid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etid);
        aetpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpass);

    }





    //creamos los metodos con los que reaccionan los btn (onClick)
    /*metodo para entrar y buscar (en construccion.... explorando metodos)*/
    public void onClickAceptar (View view) {

        String auxn = aetid.getText().toString();
        String auxp = aetpass.getText().toString();

        SQLite admin = new SQLite(this,"administracion", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase();

        fila=bd.rawQuery("select usuario, clave from usuarios where usuario='"+auxn+"'and clave='"+auxp+"'",null);



        if(fila.moveToFirst()==true){

            //capturamos los valores del cursos y lo almacenamos en variable
            String usua=fila.getString(0);
            String pass=fila.getString(1);

            //preguntamos si los datos ingresados son iguales
            if (auxn.equals(usua)&&auxp.equals(pass)){

                //si son iguales entonces vamos a otra ventana
                //Menu es una nueva actividad empty
                Intent ven=new Intent(this,MenuCentral.class);

                startActivity(ven);

                //limpiamos las las cajas de texto
                aetid.setText("");
                aetpass.setText("");

            }

        }else {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usuario o contraseña erroneo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        bd.close();
    }


    //metodo para entrar a la actividad de registro

    public void onClickRegistro(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(this,Registro.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

**ProfesoresF** (`fragment` que se genera en el `Navigation Drawer` e invoca la tabla profesores {tabla que me da el problema}

```
package company.viral.organizadorjec.FragmentMenu;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import company.viral.organizadorjec.R;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.ActivitysPrincipales.SQLite;


public class ProfesoresF extends Fragment {
    private Cursor buscador;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profesores, container, false);

        SQLite admin = new SQLite(getContext(),"administracion",null,1);
        SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase();


        buscador=bd.rawQuery("select nombreprofesor from profesores ",null);

        String [] listamateria = new String[buscador.getCount()];

        int i=0;
        while (buscador.moveToNext()){
            String contenedor = buscador.getString(buscador.getColumnIndex("nombreprofesor"));
            listamateria[i]=contenedor;
            i++;
        }

        //adaptadores
        //adaptador dias

        ListView listaprofe = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listprofef);

        ArrayAdapter<String> listavistaprofes = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listamateria);


        listaprofe.setAdapter(listavistaprofes);

        return view ;
    }



}
```

**error** este es el error que me arroja de `android monitor`

```
12-08 08:46:13.198 7388-7388/company.viral.organizadorjec E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: profesores
12-08 08:46:13.206 7388-7388/company.viral.organizadorjec E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: company.viral.organizadorjec, PID: 7388
                                                                            android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: profesores (code 1): , while compiling: select nombreprofesor from profesores
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:893)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:504)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1278)
                                                                                at company.viral.organizadorjec.FragmentMenu.ProfesoresF.onCreateView(ProfesoresF.java:29)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:536)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Ayudaría muchísimo conocer el contenido del [volcado de la pila](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces.html).

Comment: perdona soy nuevo... como asi del "volcado de la pila?" dime y lo pongo de inmediato

Comment: El error que lanza tu app cuando deja de funcionar

Comment: @sioesi ha acertado en su respuesta, no estás gestionando las actualizaciones progresivas a tu base de datos, deberás acostumbrarte a hacerlo si quieres que tus usuarios puedan actualizar sus aplicaciones sin perder datos. Tu mensaje de error dice que no existe la tabla en la que tratas de hacer la consulta SQL porque no has hecho el `CREATE TABLE` necesario. La forma más sencilla de arreglarlo es desinstalando tu aplicación y volviéndola a instalar. Eso borrará la base de datos anterior (la que no tiene la tabla nueva) y tu aplicación se verá forzada a ejecutar el código que crea las tablas.

Comment: Como no has puesto el código que usas para la creación de las tablas, no podremos ayudarte a modificarla para satisfacer actualizaciones en el esquema. Fíjate en los ejemplos que te proporciona la [documentación oficial de Android](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#DbHelper). En su ejemplo, durante una actualización (evento `onUpgrade`) borra todos los datos y vuelve a recrear las tablas que, posiblemente, no es la solución que tú deseas adoptar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el error me parece que es que tienes una base de datos antigua en tu dispositivo, por eso no encuentra la tabla aun cuando la creas. En el metodo `onUpgrade` creas nuevamente la tabla y eso esta bien ya que en futuras actualizaciones para mantener los datos es ahi donde se mantiene.

Si estas probando en algun emulador te recomiendo que veas el DDMS si el archivo de tu base de datos esta realmente cambiando su estructura.

Desintala la aplicacion desde tu telefono si es el caso y verifica nuevamente.

Te recomiendo que en cada cambio que hagas en la base de datos, elimines la base de datos y hagas inserts de prueba en tu `Activity` principal. Ya que en una fase de producción eso no seria necesario

Comment: eso era gracias :D